# Delphi XE2 TLabel glowsize causes graphic issue on top left corner of the screen

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tlabel

Ever since porting an app from XE to XE2 I noticed a strange bug, just opening the form in the ide or running the app, a white square box is drawn on the top left corner of the screen (out of the form), which goes away upon hovering the mouse or a window over. I tracked this down to TLabel, simply dropping one on the form and setting Glowsize above 0 causes the issue.

I reinstalled and updated to the last XE2 update3 and the issue still occurs. Anyone has a clue what's going on?

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem starts in `TCustomLabel.AdjustBounds` with a call to `DoDrawText` with the screen's device context and the flag DT_CALCRECT. So if anything paints on that device context, it will be painted onto the screen. The `DT_CALCRECT` flag should prevent that but the `DrawThemeTextEx` call in `Vcl.Themes.TUxThemeStyle.DoDrawText` seems to ignore the DT_CALCRECT + LOptions.dwFlags DTT_CALCRECT and paints onto the device context where it should only calculate the required rectangle. I don't know why `DrawThemeTextEx` does that (yet), but it is a starting point.

**UPDATE 1:**
Delphi 2009 doesn't seem to be affected by this but also calls DrawThemeTextEx. The only difference I see is that all unused fields of the Options record are zero whereas in Delphi XE2 they contain garbage. Maybe DrawThemeTextEx needs them to be zero.

**UPDATE 2:**
The difference between Delphi 2009 and XE2 is that in Delphi 2009 not only DTT_CALCRECT is specified but also DTT_COMPOSITE.

In Delphi 2009 the DTT_COMPOSITE is always set:

```
Options.dwFlags := DTT_TEXTCOLOR or DTT_COMPOSITED or DTT_GLOWSIZE;
```

whereas in XE2 the flag is only set if the label is painted on glass:

```
  if csGlassPaint in ControlState then
    Include(LFormat, tfComposited);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to disappear if you disable AutoSize on the label.

I didn't investigate deeper why, but as a workaround until that bug is fixed it does fine.

Comment: This seems to correlate with Andreas Hausladen's answer. He says the problem has to do with calling `DrawThemeTextEx` with `DT_CALCRECT`. I imagine that is only done when there's the need to calculate the size of the label = when the label's `AutoSize` is `True`. If you turn of `AutoSize`, no call with `DT_CALCRECT` is performed and, consequently, the bug is not produced.

Comment: Yup that works; setting autosize later after form creation and before changing the caption also seems to avoid the issue (possibly re-appearing later). It remains unfixed in latest update4.